# Trigger QLabel text update with QPushButton

Tags: python, class, parent, super

So I've tried to read up on this and am just completely baffled! Essentially, I want to modify `text` variable of my `Label` class from a function in my `Button` class. Both the `Label` and `Button` classes are instantiated within the class `Ui_Form`. I've cut out as much code as possible for the example.

```
class Button(QtGui.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, iconPath, iconX, iconY, posX, posY, posA, posB, objName, parent=None):
        super(Button, self).__init__(parent=parent) 

    def editLabel(self):
        self.filename = ntpath.basename(self.samplePath)
        edit label class here!

class Label(QtGui.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, text, posX, posY, posA, posB, objName, parent=None):
        super(Label, self).__init__(parent=parent)

        self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(posX, posY, posA, posB))
        self.font = QtGui.QFont()
        self.font.setPointSize(10)
        self.setFont(self.font)
        self.setObjectName(objName)
        self.text = text
        self.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" color:#ffffff;\">"+ self.text +"</span></p></body></html>", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
```

The instances of the classes are created in yet ANOTHER class..

```
class Ui_Form(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(591, 591)
        self.btn_a1 = Button("Python/LP_Proj/LP_Circle_Off.png", 49, 49, 30, 40, 41, 41, "btn_a1", self)
        self.lab_a1 = Label("Unassigned", 20, 76, 61, 16, "lab_a1", self)
```

Comment: You need a reference to an instance of a label in order to modify it. Perhaps you want to accept the label in the constructor of `Button`?

Comment: How would I create the reference to the label?

Comment: Add another parameter to your `Button` constructor for the label. Flip around the order of the statements where you assign `self.btn_a1` and `self.lab_a1`. Pass in `self.lab_a1` to the constructor of `self.btn_a1`. Inside the constructor of `Button`, store the label as an attribute, and you can refer to it later in the `editLabel` method.

Comment: Thank you, I thought there had to be a very simple/more 'pythonic' way to do it. Much appreciated